# Javascript push element in one array push into another

Tags: arrays, typescript

I am making a cards game in Typescript, but I have a problem drawing cards. Every player must have 8 cards at all time, and removing the card from the deck when it's drawn.

```
type PlayerObject = {
    cards: Card[];
    ...
};

class Game {
    players: PlayerObject[];
    red: Card[];
    NULL_PLAYER = {
       ...
       cards: [],
       ...
    };

    ...

    addPlayer(socket, name, id) {
        this.players.push({...Game.NULL_PLAYER, name, socket, id });
    }

    ...

    start() {
        for (const player of this.players) {
            this.giveCards(player);
        }
    }

    // When the game starts
    giveCards(player: PlayerObject) {
        const n = 8 - player.cards.length;
        for (let i = 0; i < 8 - cardsN; i++) {
            const cardIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.red.length);
            player.cards.push(this.red.splice(cardIndex, 1)[0]); // I'll reference this line
        }
    }
}
```

When `player.cards.push(...)` is executed, it pushes to every players. So when the other players draw, the `n` is always 0 and skips it.

Result: every players have the same hand.
Intended result: every player has a different hand.

Comment: Please state explicitly what your problem is. ie; what is the intended behaviour, not just the behaviour you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a medium article describing the issue: https://medium.com/@naveenkarippai/learning-how-references-work-in-javascript-a066a4e15600

In the example, I was using the cards reference in the Game.NULL_PLAYER object when adding a player to the list. and as described by the article, the arrays are not like primitive values where it makes a copy when assigning to a new varialble. As shown below:

```js
var flash = [8,8,8];
var quicksilver = flash;   //assign-by-reference
quicksilver.push(0);
console.log(flash);        //[8,8,8,0]
console.log(quicksilver);  //[8,8,8,0]
```

So every players had the same reference to the cards array and when pushing a new card for one player, it added one for everyone. The fix is to reassign the cards property to an empty array.